# Java/Android: Synchronized vs Queue implementation

Tags: java, android, synchronization, queue, synchronized

Can I ask a rookie Java question?

I am downloading some files from the web. This method download(url location) is called multiple times.

```
public static void download(final String url) {
    Thread t = new Thread("download") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (object) {
                    // download & save
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

I added "synchronized" so that downloads happens one-by-one. (not multiple downloads occur at the same time).
I am guessing even though download() is called multiple times, synchronized will block other threads until the first thread is finished.

Will above code work? or do I have to implement Queue? and dequeue one-by-one?
Can synchronized block "enough" threads? (30? 50?) or does it have limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Will above code work?***

Yes, as long as `object` refers to the same object in all threads, the code in the synchronized block will only be executed by one thread at a time.

> ***[...] or do I have to implement Queue? and dequeue one-by-one?***

Generally speaking I would recommend you to use as high-level constructs as possible (for instance from the java.util.concurrent package). You may for instance consider using an executor service for these types of things.

> ***[...] Can synchronized block "enough" threads? (30? 50?) or does it have limits?***

No, no limits. At least not near 30 or 50 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class QueueDownloader {
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    public void download(final String url) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // download & save
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will queue all runnables (i.e. downloads) on a single background-thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid creating additional threads, you should generally do so. As I understood it, you never want two work items (downloads) in parallel, so the best idea, performance-wise, is using a concurrent queue implementation that is polled by a single worker thread.