# Java Static Synchronized vs BlockingQueue implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronized, blockingqueue

I'm trying to implement an appointment queue using Servlets (resteasy + Hibernate). 
my appointment controller is as follows (simplified of course).

```
public class AppoController{

public synchronized static int createAppoinment(AppObj app){
   //get last app no
   //insert new app with no+1
   //return new app no
}
}
```

currently this method works fine. but i've read about BlockingQueue implementations which seems the correct way?

**Definition of working Fine:**

if i dont use synchronized static and send multiple requests at once multiple appointments have same appointment no 
but if i use synchronized static, appointments created with correct order

i dont use any threads here but i assume tomcat uses its own threads to server http requests from users. 
so this is a multithreaded app?

i have googled it for past few days but the closest i got is [Java/Android: Synchronized vs Queue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619641/java-android-synchronized-vs-queue-implementation)

what i need to clarify are;
- is this the correct way to do this?
- what are the pros and cons of using synchronized static vs BlockingQueue implementation for my scenario.

Any other inputs you seem relevant are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, since both approaches are restricted to a single JVM. If your service gets popular a single tomcat instance won't be able to handle all the traffic. But if you deploy your service to a second independent tomcat instance both approaches can't guarantee unique appointment numbers. Therefore the right way to solve this problem is to let the database generate the appointment numbers.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the impact of scaling. had completely missed that part! just a simple question, is there any possibility to run out of server threads in sync-static approach since they get blocked (wait)? and in contrast blockingqueue, threads (producers) never get blocked?

Comment: Yes there is, but it is (a) deprecated, (b) scheduled for removal, and (c) absolutely the last thing you want. Just synchronize on what you need to synchronize on, or use something from `java.util.concurrent.`

Comment: @EJP, thanks for pointing towards `java.util.concurrent`. i think for my requirement app no generation from DB would solve the issue. but good to know about possibilities of concurrent pack..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation does work. The synchronized method can only be executed by one thread at any time. Tomcat will use multiple threads (the details depend on the current settings, lets assume one thread per request), so every concurrent request will get its own thread and then ever request waits on this methods until its thread is allowed to enter the method.

I see two options depending on your needs.

1. If the appointment comes from a database, lets the database or hibernate handle the id generation. That would move the multi thread problem to the database which was designed to handle that kind of problem.
2. If the appointment does not come from a database and you just need a unique identifier for the appointment objects use a UUID, e.g. java.lang.UUID.randomUUID()

Actually using a Queue will only make sense if you want move the creation of the appointment out of the http request. E.g. if you create the appointment after the request finished like a nightly batch job or a dedicated worker thread pool. But this will only make sense if it is a expensive operation to create an appointment.

On a different topic, you should check if this method needs to be static.

Comment: yes appointments can be generated from DB using oninsert trigger (i have few conditions to determine new app no). and app no creation is straight forward process with hundred of users trying to access limited set of app no slots.

Comment: 'Will not scale' is a gross overstatement. *Any* solution will involved some kind of synchronization, semaphore, or lock. How well it scales depends entirely on the *duration* of that synchronization/semaphore/lock. Your own solution is no different in that respect.

Comment: Yeah "will not scale" was on overstatement. I wanted to point out, that solving the multithreaded problem on your own is normally a bad idea. Just move the problem to a system that was designed for this kind a of problem, like a database.